# How to group data in jqgrid depending on column data

Tags: angularjs, jqgrid, grouping

I have implemented a jqgrid with grouping, but recently I found that another grouping tab is getting created for the same name(warning) when ever I insert a new record in the db.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF69A.png)

I want all the records with warning to be in the same group and not in separate group tab.

```
 datatype: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
        serializeGridData: function (postData) { return JSON.stringify(postData); },
        width: gwdth - 30,
        height: 580,
        colNames: ['ID', 'Icon', 'Path', 'Source', 'Name', 'Severity', 'Resolution State', 'Age', 'Created Date', 'Repeat Count'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', hidden: true, width: 1, key: true },
                { name: 'severity', width: 20, edittype: 'image', formatter: imageIcon, align: "center" },
                { name: 'path', width: 30 },
                { name: 'source', width: 30 },
                { name: 'name', width: 30 },
                { name: 'severity', width: 30, hidden: true },
                { name: 'resolutionState', width: 30 },
                { name: 'age', width: 30 },
                { name: 'createdDate', width: 30, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'y-m-d', newformat: 'l, F d, Y' } },
                { name: 'occuranceCount', width: 30, align: "center" }
        ],

        loadonce: true,
        rowNum: 25,
        rowList: [20, 30, 50],
        gridview: true,
        mtype: 'GET',
        sortname: 'ID',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortable: true,
        pager: "#jqGridPagerA2log",
        grouping: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ['severity'],
            groupColumnShow: [true],
            groupText: ['<b>{0}({1})</b>'],
            groupOrder: ["asc"],
            groupSummary: false,
            groupCollapse: true
        }
    });
```

I need to group based on severity column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On seeing your image, and content that you have posted, I believe that by getting the data in order (order by) would solve your problem.